# vb.net how to solve 2 issues with single and double click on notify icon

Tags: vb.net, events, system-tray

I have a vb.net (.NET 3.0) app which has a NotifyIcon in the system tray. I would like the single left-click and double left-click events to do different things; `.Click` should open the app's context menu, and `.DoubleClick` should take some default action. So this is my code at the moment:

```
Private Sub showMenu(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
Handles Tray.Click
    Debug.Print("click")
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = GetType(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        mi.Invoke(Tray, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub defaultAction(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Tray.DoubleClick
    Debug.Print("double click")
    doDefaultAction()
End Sub
```

The first problem is that the `.Click` handler is fired even for a double-click - it responds to the first click rather than waiting to see if it was actually a double-click. Maybe this is normal behaviour, but is there a 'best practice' way of trapping that occurrence without horrible kludges involving timers? From what I've read on SO, I suspect not. However, that's not the most serious problem...

The second, bigger, problem is that the `doDefaultAction()` code does various things, one of which is to download an xml file from a specific URL. I'm doing this with this line of code (note not the actual URL:):

```
Dim reader = XmlReader.Create("http://server.com/genxml.php")
```

As soon as execution reaches that line, *another* `.Click` event is fired, so the debug output looks like this:

```
click
double click
click
```

That second click event re-opens the context menu, and because `doDefaultAction()` goes on to show a modal `MessageBox`, the menu gets stuck open. I've stepped through in the debugger, and if I 'Step Into' that `Dim reader` line, I get taken straight to `Sub showMenu()` above. Very odd. Any ideas what could cause that?

Comment: typically, the right-click opens the context menu and therefore shouldn't interfere with the double-click of the left button.

Comment: I think this is bad design. A DblClick should not do anything that requires to circumvent the single click event. (E. g. often a click selects an item, DblClick opens/executes something -> Opening does not require to prevent the selection. It is logically sequential.) Use the middle button click, or CTRL-Click etc., or context menu items (via RIGHT mouse button) for any additional functions. (I did not downvote though)

Comment: Erm, OK. Thanks for the design advice :). There are plenty of examples of system tray apps where a left click (and/or right click) will give you a menu (Win8 Action Centre, Safely Remove Hardware, etc.), and apps like Dropbox which use a left-click for menu, and double click to open the folder. However, and even though I would tend to agree with you, the design is unfortunately not up to me. And in any case, I'm _more_ interested in the second problem, which definitely looks like a programming issue. Any thoughts on that one?